# To do no wrong To do no harm

Tags: grammar

I've just heard very interesting sentence on popular TV channel. It said sth like that :

> Hitler is not that kind of man. **He does no wrong**

I know what could that mean "*He does not make mistakes*" but, is this sentence correct in terms of grammar ?

I know there is something like "*Do no harm*" and this is acceptable because "*do*" behaves like "*have*".

e.g "*I have no money*"

Can somebody explain to me how these processes work ? Also there is double negative here "*no wrong*"

Comment: *Wrong* is not a negative.It's like saying "He makes no errors".

Comment: So there is nothing WRONG with this sentence ?

Comment: The sentence is grammatical. Are you trying to say something by putting "wrong" in uppercase?  "Negative" in the grammatical sense does not mean "unfavorable" or "possessing undesirable qualities", it refers to the negation of a predicate.

Comment: For example:  "This substance is *not* water."

Comment: Well, whatever you were watching, saying Hitler does no wrong is just.. wrong.

Answer (score 1):

> He does no wrong.

It's a perfectly grammatical sentence.

For example you say something -

> He does homework.

**subject** -> *He*

**Verb Phrase** -> *does homework* [ **Verb** -> *does* and **Object of the verb** -> homework]

Notice the **object of the verb** is a noun phrase.

Your original sentence has the same structure.

> He does no wrong.

**Subject** -> *He*

**Verb Phrase** -> *does no wrong* [**Verb** -> *does* and **Object of the verb** -> *no wrong*]

**Object of the verb** -> *determiner + noun* -> *no + wrong*

Answer (score 1):

"wrong" can be a noun: a sense of right and wrong - to know right from wrong - to do wrong -to do sb a wrong - to suffer a wrong -and others.